# Eloquent relationship with one-to-one sub types

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am working with an ad system. So an `Ad` has 2 concrete types `Text` and `Banner`.

In ads table, there's `ad_id` and `ad_type` where type refers to either `Text` or `Banner` and id their PK. So Ad->concrete should return either `Text` or `Banner`.

**How do I implement this in Eloquent? All the polymorphic examples in the doc are for many-to-many or many-to-one relationship but mine is a one-to-one.**

I can do a hasOne from `Ad` by first getting the type back and using it, but is there a better way to do this? From what I've read this does not support eagar-loading.

```
//In AdModel
public function concrete() {
    return $this->hasOne($this->ad_type, 'ad_id');
}
```

Comment: I realize there is `morphOne()` method? I have not tried this though. I would be really interested in seeing how this is solved.

Comment: I was looking at morphOne but I am not sure how to use the first param since there are more than one classes.

Comment: the morphOne() would definitely be in the Text and Banner model, I guess it would still be like `return $this->morphOne(Banner::class, 'ad_id');` By the way I guess you have to enforce a unique constraint on your table, for both `$table->unique(['ad_id', 'ad_type'], 'id_type_index');`

Comment: I think a belongsTo() from the subclass will be more appropriate though I am unclear about the inner workings of the method. Found these 2 links that are relevant: 1. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/one-to-one-polymorphic-inverse-relationship-with-existing-database 2. https://github.com/Nanigans/single-table-inheritance

Comment: Could you not use single table inheritance for this? It dosn't seem that ad type is needed for anything other than choosing the class.

Comment: @JeremyFrench Yes, I am looking into it now. It does not support Laravel 5.4 yet though. And it seems I must put all my data in one table. In practice, I have lots of sub classes with varied data structure.